# do object references to redux store stay the same between rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using a useEffect hook like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllArticles(client);
  }, [client]);
```

where `client` is another object from my redux store.

Since redux store is immutable does that mean the object reference stays the same (meaning my useEffect won't be called unless the values in client changes) or do I need to put each value from client that I need into the dependency array by itself to prevent unnecessary api calls?